# How to prevent Android from killing my Unity app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing an augmented reality app with Unity where users can shoot a photo with their mobile device to add 3D objects on it. The problem is that on Android, when the user chooses to shoot a photo from my app, the app is put on the background and often closed instead of being kept in memory to handle the photo taken. I know it is because of Android killing apps to free ram.. But is there a way to prevent the killing of my app ? Even on Ipad 2 with its 512Mo of ram IOS doesn't do this brutal killing thing : after the shooting it goes back smoothly to the app. Whereas Android does it with my 1Go of ram phone. 
Also I do not want my app being killed and restarted by a service to handle the photo because it is pretty heavy to load and so really far from starting instantly.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.runInBackground` is disabled on mobile platforms and therefore Unity cannot guarantee that your game/app is kept running. This behaviour is normal as the OS kills activities as needed. Sadly Android is resource hungry and therefore apps that stay in the background on iOs might be killed on Android, even with better hardware.

As hinted in [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/117723-Application-runInBackground-is-not-working-on-Android) you have a few options: use states to handle pause/resume, create a service that will keep running in the background (it will have to be created outside of Unity either via a plugin or in eclipse) and/or use Android's intents mechanism.